# Error from program using SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I would like to use the SymPy packages to find the roots of a fourth-order polynomial equation. Subsequently I would like to plot these roots as a function of the parameters of the polynomial equations. I have written the piece of code below. It seems to calculate everything fine, but I cannot plot the results as I get the error "x and y are not of the same dimension". I think it has something to do with my usage of SymPy, because normally it always works like this.

```
     from sympy import *
     from math  import *
     from numpy import *
     import pylab as lab

     def RootFunc(root, m, c0, r, En):

         A = 2*(m**2 - 0.25 - c0**2)/r**2 + 4
         B = 8*En*c0/r
         C = -4 - 4*En**2 + ((c0**2 + m**2 -.25)/r**2 + 2)**2

         return root.subs([(a,A),(b,B),(c,C)])

     # Define necessary symbols
     x         = symbols('x')
     a, b, c   = symbols('a b c')
     En, r     = symbols("En r")

     # Fix constants
     m  = 0
     c0 = -2

     # Solve equation
     eq = x**4 + a*x**2 + b*x + c
     sol = solve(eq,x)

     root1 = sol[0]

     grid = linspace(1,10,10)

     sol1 = [RootFunc(root1, m, c0, r, .5) for r in grid]

     lab.figure(1)
     lab.plot(grid,sol1)
     lab.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that you a running the same script that you've given us here?

I say this because I can copy and paste your example verbatim and it works with absolutely no issue.

Once you've checked, could you post which version of Python, SymPy, NumPy and Matplotlib you're using please?

**Edit:** I think something got slightly lost in translation when you put up your first minimal working example (MWE). The solution in your MWE was real-valued so it didn't have the same issue as your actual program. However, onto the solution:

Your main issue here is this line

```
sol1 = [RootFunc(root1, m, c0, help, .5) for help in grid]
```

`RootFunc` in this case returns a `sympy.core.add.Add` which `pylab` has no concept of and therefore can't plot. In your MWE you recognised that this was the issue and tried calling `N()` and `real()` on the return value. Unfortunately this just wraps the `sympy.core.add.Add` object in a NumPy array. When Pylab tries to plot this array it finds a `sympy.core.add.Add` object which it has no concept of and therefore just throws an error.

Fortunately SymPy allows you to turn a `sympy.core.add.Add` object into a number using `int()`, `float()` or `complex()`. Since your roots are complex you should use `complex()` on the return value and then to get the real component use `.real`.

So to get it too work you should just change the above line to

```
sol1 = [complex(RootFunc(root1, m, c0, help, .5)).real for help in grid]
```

**Edit2:** Just a quick point about style. You're using a lot of wildcard imports in your code (e.g. `from numpy import *`), which is fine if you're the only person using the code, it does make it neater after all.

However, if you're going to be posting on a forum like this please could you try to use qualified imports (like you've done for `pylab`) so that we don't have to go trudging through the documentation for all the modules you've used to try and figure out what you're doing.

One other thing: when you encounter a problem like this it really helps to execute it line by line in the python shell and examine the types (with `type()`) and values (with `print()` or `repr()`) of your variables. For this purpose I would strongly urge you to learn how to use [IPython](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/index.html) as it can really help.

Comment: I have found a mistake. Apparently the line "[real(N(RootFunc(root1, 1, grid))) for grid in grid]" changes grid from an array to one number. However, if I replace this with "[real(N(RootFunc(root1, 1, help))) for help in grid]", I get a different error. Any ideas?

Comment: Firstly which error do you get? And secondly could you show us what your value for `sol1` is before you plot it?

Comment: I have edited my post to show my unmodified program. Perhaps you can try if it works for you?

Comment: I've updated my answer, let me know whether it's worked.

Comment: It works now, thank you very much! Thanks for looking into this. I promise I will pay more attention to my style in the future :)

Comment: Perfect, I'm glad it worked, and hopefully you understand now why it didn't work originally. As for style, it's one of those things that seems silly until you have to share you code, then it can become very important. But it comes with experience mostly, and besides even Python gurus can't decide on what "good style" really is. If you do find yourself in the situation where you're sharing code more often though, I would look into [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) as it might give you some good tips.

Answer (score 1):

You might be breaking some things with your imports. Can you try this:

```
import sympy as sy
import numpy as np
import pylab as lab

def RootFunc(root, A, B):

    return root.subs([(a,A),(b,B)])

# Define necessary symbols
x         = sy.symbols('x')
a, b      = sy.symbols('a b')

# Solve equation
eq = x**4 + a*x**2 + b*x
sol = sy.solve(eq,x)
root1 = sol[1] # first element is trivial solution, so take second one

grid = np.linspace(1,10,10)
sol1 = [np.real(sy.N(RootFunc(root1, 1, x))) for x in grid]

lab.figure(1)
lab.plot(grid,sol1)
lab.show()
```

Comment: yes this works. However, I get a different error with my 'real' code (my post was just a minimal working example). I have update my post. Could you have a look.

Comment: I am now and the error I get is "PolynomialError: cannot return general quartic solution" hence a different issue :)

Comment: Haha, I do not get that error. Instead I get "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence"

Comment: Importing numpy as np, it seems to be ok if I edit this line `sol1 = [np.array((RootFunc(root1, m, c0, help, .5)), dtype = complex).real for help in grid]`  (try `type(sol1[0])`) to see what's going on there). NB: only the real part is drawn then.